# Counting number of observations with sampling weights

Tags: stata

I have a time-id survey dataset in Stata with a sampling weight like below:

```
ID time var1 var2 weight
1  1997  1    10    400
1  1998  2     1    200
1  1999  4     .    50.3
2  1997  2     .    13.2
2  1998  3     5    150
```

I would like to count all individuals who have `var1==1` or `var1==2` per year, accounting for the sampling weight given as 'weight' above. I know how I can count the observations without accounting for the weight, like below:

```
gen var1count = .
foreach i of numlist 1997/1999 {
    count if (var1==1 | var1==2) & time==`i'
    replace var1count = r(N) if time==`i'
```

However, I'm unsure how I can incorporate sampling weight (pweight) when I'm counting the number of observations that meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
clear 
input ID time var1 var2 weight
    1  1997  1    10    400
    1  1998  2     1    200
    1  1999  4     .    50.3
    2  1997  2     .    13.2
    2  1998  3     5    150
end 

egen wanted = total(weight * inlist(var1, 1, 2)), by(time)

tabdisp time, c(wanted)

----------------------
     time |     wanted
----------+-----------
     1997 |      413.2
     1998 |        200
     1999 |          0
----------------------
```